# using strncmp for selection in string

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

I am new to the C code. For this particular code if the user inputs the name

> john,

`"john is cool"` will be printed. I don't think I am using `strncmp()` properly.
Can someone please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char namedata[50], names;


int counter = 0, n;


printf("Enter Number of family members being enter into program \n");
scanf("%d", &n);

for (names=0; names<n; ++names)
{

printf("Enter family member name:\n");
scanf("%s",namedata);
counter = counter +1;
printf("name:");
puts(namedata);

}
if (strncmp (name,"john") == 0)
{
  printf ("found %s\n",name);
}


return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `strncmp` takes [three](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strncmp.htm) arguments

Comment: It's common to add 1 to a variable like so: `counter++;`

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp

Comment: If you want to read in multiple strings, you need to have a 2-dimensional char array: `char namedata[50][50];`. This one can hold 50 strings with a length of 49 and one ending zero character (`\0`) for each string.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Please do not change the actual question in a way that makes the existing answers invalid. [edit] and add the updated info after the actual question so that the existing answers remain valid. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean takes three arguments? Sorry if I ask too many questions...

Comment: The word 'three' in @Pynchia's comment is a [hyperlink](http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/h/f/What-Are-Hyperlinks.htm).

Answer (score 3):

You're facing a logical issue here. You only have one array named

```
char namedata[50]
```

for which, you're taking `n` inputs, each overwriting the previous one. So, only the last input will remain. If you want an array of "name"s, you need to use a 2D array to store all the names, something along the line of

```
char namedata[50][50];
```

and

```
scanf("%49s",namedata[names]);
```

and the comparison should also be done in the same range loop to check for each value in the array.

That said,

1. The usage of [`strncpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) is wrong. See the man page for the proper usage.
2. `scanf("%s",namedata);` is potentially unsafe from buffer overflow. Atleast, use `scanf("%49s",namedata);` to avoid overflow by longer inputs.
3. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: prog.c:18:23: error: 'name' undeclared (first use in this function)
 scanf("%49s",namedata[name]); I changed everything but I keep getting that error on Ideone.com

Comment: @MikeR oops, it should be `names`, but is that really something you should ask me to fix? :-)

Comment: Yea I seen that my bad it still throws these errors         prog.c:18:1: warning: array subscript has type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]
 scanf("%49s",namedata[names]);        prog.c:23:26: error: macro "strncmp" requires 3 arguments, but only 2 given
 if (strncmp (names,"john") == 0)         prog.c:23:28: warning: the comparison will always evaluate as 'false' for the address of 'strncmp' will never be NULL [-Waddress]
 if (strncmp (names,"john") == 0)
                            ^

Comment: @MikeR those errors are verbose enough. change `char names` to `int names` and read my answer again to fix those errors.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least do:

```
for (names=0; names<n; ++names) {
 printf("Enter family member name:\n");
 scanf("%s",namedata);
 counter++; // don't know what this is used for
 printf("name:");
 puts(namedata);
 if (strncmp(name,"john", 4) == 0) { // strncmp takes three arguments
  printf ("found %s\n",name);
  break; // exit the loop maybe?
 }
}
```

But, in case you want the program to collect all the names and then look for the ones named `john`, you need to store the given names in their own area, as the previous answer mentioned.
In order to do that you will need an array of pointers to char and learn how to allocate/free memory.

Have fun!
:)

Answer (score 0):

I got it thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char namedata[50];

int n, names;
printf("Enter Number of family members being enter into program \n");
scanf("%d", &n);
    for (names=0; names<n; ++names)
    {

    printf("Enter family member name:\n");
    scanf("%s", &namedata);
    printf("name:");
    puts(namedata);

    }
        if (strcmp(namedata,"crystal")==0)
        {
         printf("crsytal is cool");
         }
return 0;   
}
```